# Weird Jquery/CSS Menu Issue

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a jquery drop down menu with jquery and css to style it.

However, every time you hover over the menu options and go back and forth, it seems to leave pieces of the menu left over.  Any ideas where this is coming from and how to get rid of it?

Here is the code in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2msuP/2/

See the page and how it works here: http://f4design.com/clients/bigiochame/index.html

I am noticing it in Safari.  It may not be apparent in all browsers. However, the main user for this site will be Safari users.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Kevin

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm on Chrome in Linux and cannot replicate your issue

Comment: He said Safari. I can replicate it in Safari too, and it looks like a bug in the browser to me, without looking at the code.

Comment: For starters, you can remove the `<script>` tag in your JS fiddle.  That will remove all of the garbage at the start.

Answer (score 0):

For people wondering, he's talking about the following effect when mousing over the navigation very quickly.

Looks like a redraw issue.

[image]

I'm finding ideas online about ways to force Safari to redraw, but so far my attempts are not working. Still, thought this SS should be useful.